# How to include external library in testing library/storybook

Tags: react-redux, materialize, react-testing-library, storybook

I'm using Storybook to create stories. I want to create tests of the stories using `@storybook/testing-react`. However, I'm also using `materialize-react` which requires that `materialize.min.js` is loaded.

I am loading this in `.storybook/preview-head.html` and it works for storybook.

But when I run a test (created as in https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/testing-react), I'm getting `Error: Uncaught [ReferenceError: M is not defined]` which I'm pretty sure means that `materialize.min.js` is not loaded.

How do I load an external JS file in testing library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can achieve the above by appending the following to `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test --setupFiles ./public/materialize.min.js",
  },
```

I'm not sure if this is the "best" way.